# How can I make proper doors in Godot?

Tags: godot

[Here's the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQ8z5.gif) 
I want to have a door interaction where you click once and while it opens if you click again animation reverses midway and closes door. First I tried to attach animation on the door and static body and tried to play animation via play_backwards function. When you spam too many interaction on door animation player glitches and starts from the very beginning. Eventually I gave up and seperated open and close animation. I have created an animationtree and blended two animations but it didnt work like I imagined in the first place.

Code I am using:

```
func interact():
    
    if !locked:
        
        if !open:
            open = true
            $door_anim.play("open")
            
        else:
            open = false
            $door_anim.play_backwards("open")
            
    else:
        $door_sound_locked.play()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two animations approach would work if the animation cannot be interrupted.

Allowing the animation to interrupt is tricky. I would suggest to only use `play`, set the `custom_speed` to make it go backwards, and right after calling play use `seek` or `advance` to go to the position in the animation from where you want it to play... Which means you need to read the current position in the animation before calling `play`:

```
var anim:AnimationPlayer = $door_anim

var current_position := 0.0
if anim.is_playing():
    current_position = anim.current_animation_position
elif open:
    current_position = anim.get_animation("open").length

anim.play("open", -1.0, -1.0 if open else 1.0)
anim.seek(current_position)
open = not open
```

---

Let us go over it:

Of course, this is getting the animation player:

```
var anim:AnimationPlayer = $door_anim
```

This mess is figuring out what should be the current position:

```
var current_position := 0.0
if anim.is_playing():
    current_position = anim.current_animation_position
elif open:
    current_position = anim.get_animation("open").length
```

We have three cases:

- The animation is playing: take the current position
- The animation is not playing:

  - And the door is open, we want the end position of the animation (i.e. the length of the animation).
  - And the door is closed, we want the start of the animation (i.e. `0.0`).

Note: you might also check `anim.current_animation == "open"` if there are other animations.

Here I play the animation, the speed will be `-1.0` (backwards) if the door is `open`, or `1.0` (forward) otherwise:

```
anim.play("open", -1.0, -1.0 if open else 1.0)
```

Since playing the animation would reset it, I set the current position of the animation:

```
anim.seek(current_position)
```

And finally, this is toggling `open`:

```
open = not open
```

Hopefully that makes sense, *and works*.

---

If that does not work, I would suggest setting the animation playback mode to manual, and then handling it in `_process`.

First, promote `current_position` to a field:

```
var _current_position := 0.0
```

We are going to keep track of the current position instead of figuring it out on the interaction.

So the interaction code is simpler:

```
var anim:AnimationPlayer = $door_anim
anim.play("open")
open = not open
```

Here we don't worry about how to call `play` since we will take control of the animation playback. Remember to set the animation playback mode to "manual". However, we are making sure the animation is playing (I do not expect restarting it to cause problems, because, again, we will be in control of the playback, but if it does, you can check `anim.is_playing()`).

And in `_process` we do this:

```
func _process(delta: float) -> void:
    var anim:AnimationPlayer = $door_anim
    if anim.is_playing():
        var speed := 1.0 if open else -1.0
        var next_position := clampf(
            _current_position + delta * speed,
            0.0,
            anim.current_animation_length
        )

        var delta_position := next_position - _current_position
        if delta_position == 0.0:
            anim.stop()
        else:
            anim.advance(delta_position)
            anim.seek(next_position, true)
            _current_position = next_position
```

If the animation player is not playing we do nothing.

We are figuring out the speed of the animation depending on the current value of `open` each frame. Thus it should always be correct.

We compute the next position of the animation given the elapsed time between frames, the prior position, and the speed we figured out... And we clamp it to the length of the animation. Then we see if the new position is different (it won't if it reached the end), if it is we advance the animation player (I use both `advance` and `seek` due to an [old bug](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/issues/48982)), and, of course, update the current position.

I would also suggest to store `current_animation_length` in a variable instead of reading it each time, but I'll leave that to your discretion.

---

*If it does not work, I would probably fallback to handling the transform of the door directly from code to make the rotation animation to open it and close it.*